# Problem with stimulsoft report on asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, iis, stimulsoft

I'm using stimulsoft report Ver.2023 on an old asp.net webforms project(.Net framework 4.8). It's generate reports and export them as pdf to download by users. On my local computer everything goes right. But when I deploy project on IIS server, after 2-3 weeks no pdf can generate.

I checked windows logs on server and get some error like 'FileNotFoundException' .... "C:\windows\temp\x4fr3542.dll" not found.
(names of files are random but path is fixed).
Replacing server with new machine fixes the problem for 2-3 weeks.
What would I do?

Comment: You pay them for a license and support. What did their support say?

Comment: Stimulsoft Reports is a paid product, the first 2-3 weeks should be a trial period, and this error occurred later because of the need to pay for it.